# Confused with Generic Interfaces

Tags: c#, covariance

Any help would be appreciated. I am following a video on plural sight but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am getting this error

> Error 5   The type 'Domain.Business.Entities.Employee' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Core.Common.DataRepositoryBase'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'Domain.Business.Entities.Employee' to
>   'Core.Common.Contracts.IIdentifiableEntity'.  C:\Users\ibraheem\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Practice\EF_MVC_Practice\Employees.Data\Repositories\EmployeeRepository.cs   11  18  Employees.Data

This is what my code looks like

```
public interface IDataRepository
{

}

public interface IDataRepository<T> : IDataRepository where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity, new()
{ 
  //do stuff
}


public abstract class DataRepositoryBase<T, U> : IDataRepository<T> 
    where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity, new()
     where U : DbContext, new()
{

}

//this is where I get the error
public class EmployeeRepository : DataRepositoryBase<Employee, EmployeesContext>
{
}
```

Edit:

```
    public class Employee : IIdentifiableEntity
{}
```

solved:
EmployeeRepository never implemented IIdentifiableEntity

Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: What is the definition of `Employee`?

Comment: Does Employee implement IIdentifiableEntity?

Comment: Most likely, `Employee` does not implement `IIdentifiableEntity` as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: `EmployeeRepository` never implemented `IIdentifiableEntity`

Thanks for everyones help.